# Oozie HA using HAProxy load balancer

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, oozie, high-availability

I have a cluster being monitored using Cloudera Manager. The goal was to enable HA for the cluster components, which works perfectly until Oozie HA came to picture.

For now, I have 1 Oozie server on host XXX.XXX.XXX.246. If I understood correctly, enabling Oozie HA will create another Oozie server and connect both of the servers to the load balancer. My second Oozie server should be on host XXX.XXX.XXX.247. For these purposes, I have installed haproxy on the host XXX.XXX.XXX.248, but cannot seem to configure it.

This is my haproxy.cfg file:

```
listen loadbalancer XXX.XXX.XXX.248:80
mode http
stats enable
stats uri /haproxy?stats
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
server  oozie1 XXX.XXX.XXX.246:11000 check
server  oozie2 XXX.XXX.XXX.247:11000 check
```

I assume my ports have not been chosen correctly, but I am new to this topic, so I don`t understand it very well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using port 11000 in the load balancer instead of 80.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Thank you, but, unfortunately, that did not solve the problem.

Comment: http://crazyadmins.com/tag/oozie-ha-loadbalancer/

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to repicate this one, but Cloudera and Ambari are not compatible.